# Push Notification Not Working iOS Using FCM

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have implemented FCM. There is no error showing. Token successfully generated. But no notification coming into the device.

I followed the google documentations.

Here is my AppDelegate class

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase

//https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/5694c29ac5a8dcc672ec13f55f0ab74a6b9af11e/messaging/MessagingExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift#L40-L55
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

    FirebaseApp.configure()
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

              // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

      let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: authOptions,
        completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    
    return true
}


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
  print(userInfo)
}

// [START receive_message]
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
  // Print full message.
  print(userInfo)
  completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
  print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
    
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
  print("Firebase registration token: \(String(describing: fcmToken))")
  
  let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
  NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)

}


}
```

didReceiveRegistrationToken **delegate method callings twice**

Here is my Capabilities[image]

I tried send notification from firebase cloud messaging option, but not coming to any Push in device.
I also tried from postman. Here is my payload and output

[image]

I have uploaded the APNS certificate in firebabse .
[image]

I tried into main project and its not working.
Then I tried to fresh implement into a dummy project its also not working.

Here is my source code. You may check into this.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/22wojqv5u3vwjzt/Swift%20UI%20Push%20Notification.zip?dl=0

Comment: check the payload but in the documentation fcm payload for APNS is different

Comment: Always had a tough time using FCM on iOS, always works better on Android.
Once had a long discussion with Firebase team over their unstable FCM for iOS.
Please use APNs in future, it's always stable.

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Please update on whether your case is now resolved and the key difference you needed to make, or is this still unresolved?  I have found myself similarly placed and I have come to believe that the fault is something minor having followed good directions and having the Android side working fine.  I just read about the [APNS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/generating_a_remote_notification) and looked at my payload and thought of changes I could make.

Answer (score 1):

I think the payload is different for APNS.From the document I found that the following is the format for FCM payload in APNS

```
 {
   "message":  {
                "token" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
                "notification" : {
                                  "body" : "This is an FCM notification that displays an image.!",
                                  "title" : "FCM Notification",
                                  },
                "apns": {
                       "payload": {
                                  "aps": {
                                         "mutable-content": 1
                                         }
                                  },
                "fcm_options": {
                                "image": "url-to-image"
                                }
                        }
               }
 }
```

Comment: This is not working from the postman. However, my payload was working in my other application.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend running the iOS side of Flutter projects in Xcode.  The Xcode feedback for errors is very AI-like, they are official Apple information, and progress can be made sooner.  I would be stuck exactly where this question is based had it not been for running my code in Xcode (version 15.2).  Android Studio is nice for Android coding, but Xcode goes into detail on errors and error-resolution for iOS coding which Android Studio does not notice or report at all.

```js
2024-01-26 15:47:51.652013+0000 Runner[669:15902] 10.18.0 - [FirebaseCore][I-COR000008] The project's Bundle ID is inconsistent with either the Bundle ID in 'GoogleService-Info.plist', or the Bundle ID in the options if you are using a customized options. To ensure that everything can be configured correctly, you may need to make the Bundle IDs consistent. To continue with this plist file, you may change your app's bundle identifier to 'com.example.myApp'. Or you can download a new configuration file that matches your bundle identifier from https://console.firebase.google.com/ and replace the current one.
2024-01-26 15:47:51.761606+0000 Runner[669:15902] 10.18.0 - [FirebaseMessaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. Follow the instructions at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging
to ensure proper integration.
2024-01-26 15:11:55.643576+0000 Runner[423:8565] 10.18.0 - [FirebaseCore][I-COR000003] The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add `FirebaseApp.configure()` to your application initialization. This can be done in in the App Delegate's application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` (or the `@main` struct's initializer in SwiftUI).
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add all the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate method along with completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound]).